# What are useful/new areas to work on for recommendation systems?

Tags: recommendation-systems, filtering-problem

I am working on a project on recommendation systems, and would like to know about specific areas/research papers on which some new work can be performed, but not something too time/coding intensive. Its for a project due in 2 months.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. We prefer questions that have objectively correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have the same question in the future. What is or is not a suitable topic for study, projects or research is very much a matter of opinion and depends crucially on the interests and skills of the person who will be doing the work and the support that will be available to them. This is a question that you should be asking your professors.

Comment: How do I reword the question to fit the guidelines? My professor isn't of much help in this, so I'd pretty much like to crowd source ideas.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't.  It's not a matter of wording -- the type of question just doesn't work well here.  Our site format works for a particular type of questions, so we focus on only those questions -- even though there are others that might be interesting, they don't work here.  If you participate more, enough to enter chat, you could join our [chat] room.  Alternatively, you could look for some other site that does accept this type of question.  Or, you could read research papers in this area to learn about work that's being done currently.  Good luck with your project!